# as.POSIXct() produces NA for specific date times

Tags: r, datetime, statistics, posixct

I am currently analyzing a chunk of around 40k tweets using R. Therefore, I am converting text to dates using `as.POSIXct()`. While this works for almost all rows, I have two rows in the set which result in `NA` being returned.

I already narrowed it down to a one-hour-timespan on a specific date (see below). Also changing anything else (year, month, etc.) works as well.

```
dateFormat <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

working1 <- as.POSIXct("2014-03-30 01:59:59", format = dateFormat)
### everything in between does not work
working2 <- as.POSIXct("2014-03-30 03:00:00", format = dateFormat)

### These were the original dates:
notWorking1 <- as.POSIXct("2014-03-30 02:39:21", format = dateFormat)
notWorking2 <- as.POSIXct("2014-03-30 02:33:28", format = dateFormat)
```

I am not sure if I found a bug or this is my fault since I am still learning R.

Comment: It works for me but I am guessing from `I already narrowed it down to a one-hour-timespan on a specific date` if it is related to Daylight saving in your time zone ?

Comment: Good call, Ronak, and this is a sure dupe as I answered that type of question at least two or three times as well...

Comment: Thanks for the hint Ronak. You might be right since after I explicitly set the timezone to UTC it works.

Comment: 30th of march looks suspicious at first glance :) 

if all works out we're done with this daylight saving nonsense in the eu in 2021

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out by Ronak in the comments, this was a DST issue.

> It works for me but I am guessing from `I already narrowed it down to a one-hour-timespan on a specific date` if it is related to Daylight saving in your time zone ?